# Fazer com que um START TRANSACTION não reserve o ID das tabelas envolvidas, em caso de falha no insert

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Olá amigos desenvolvedores,

Montei um script **transaction** para inserir valores em 2 tabelas diferentes, coloquei um **or die** no fim de cada INSERT, para que a inserção de dados não ocorra na segunda tabela, caso ocorra um erro na inserção da primeira.

O que tem me incomodado é que mesmo que ocorra um erro na inserção dos dados e o processo morra (não inserindo os dados no banco), ainda assim **a ID das tabelas é reservada**, fazendo com que em um próximo INSERT bem sucedido, **a ID não esteja sequencial em relação ao registro anterior.**
OBS: As duas tabelas tem auto_increment na ID.

Existe alguma forma de resolver esse problema?

**Segue abaixo um exemplo do meu código:**

```
    $mysqli->query('START TRANSACTION') or die($mysqli->error);

    $sql = "INSERT endereco (logradouro, numero, complemento, bairro, cidade, uf) VALUES ('".$logradouro."','".$numero."','".$complemento."','".$bairro."','".$cidade."','".$uf."')"; 
    $query = $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error);
    $idEndereco = $mysqli->insert_id;

    $sql = "INSERT contato (email, telefone, telefone_adicional) VALUES ('".$email."','".$telefone."','".$telefoneAdicional."')";
    $query = $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error);
    $idContato = $mysqli->insert_id;

    $mysqli->query('COMMIT') or die($mysqli->error);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é uma característica do AUTO INCREMENT, segundo a própria documentação:

> **“Lost” auto-increment values and sequence gaps**
>
> In all lock modes (0, 1, and 2), if a transaction that generated auto-increment values rolls back, those auto-increment values are “lost”. Once a value is generated for an auto-increment column, it cannot be rolled back, whether or not the “INSERT-like” statement is completed, and whether or not the containing transaction is rolled back. Such lost values are not reused. Thus, there may be gaps in the values stored in an AUTO_INCREMENT column of a table.

[Fonte](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html)

*Em resumo: em qualquer modo de bloqueio (0, 1 e 2), se uma transação que gerou um valor do `auto-increment` falhar, esses valores serão perdidos. Esses valores não podem ser reutilizados. Assim, poderá haver lacunas nos valores armazenados na coluna AUTO_INCREMENT da tabela.*

---

Uma fez que você gera o AUTO INCREMENT você não pode reverter os valores já gerados, segundo a própria documentação, o que reduz as chances disso realmente ser possível. Não vejo absolutamente nenhum problema em haver lacunas, "deixar de ser sequencial".

Comment: Agradeço pela resposta Inkeliz!